# Hide javascript zoom for CSS Hidden list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image gallery based on a list where css hides the unselected image with the gallery images selected by thumbnail links, as per the code below. I use the Jquery 'elevate zoom' function to zoom in on the main images on mouseover, but find that the 'hidden' list elements are only visual -- my js/jquery zooms are still present and pop-up whenever the mouse is over the other hidden list elements. I know little about javascript and don't relish dipping into the hundreds of code-lines of the elevate zoom function. Is there any way to tie the js behaviour to the css?

CSS:

```
#gallery {
width: 560px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 430px;}

#gallery-interior li {
width: 560px;
height: 430px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul id="gallery-interior">
<li id="one"><img id="zoom_01" src="../images/normal_1.jpg" data-zoom-image="../images/big_1.jpg"></li>
<li id="two"><img id="zoom_02" src="../images/normal_2.jpg" data-zoom-image="../images/big_2.jpg"></li>
</ul>

<div>
<a href="#one"><img src="../images/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
<a href="#two"><img src="../images/thumb_2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle or something else illustrating what you're asking? It's not very apparent, given the code and markup above, what you're asking for.

Comment: @JB. Does jsfiddle have directory access as I would have to upload the files jquery.min.js and elevatezoom.js to show the behaviour? The basic problem is that css 'hidden' hides the other gallery image but there is nothing to hide the data-zoom image when the mouse is over the hidden list elements.

Comment: jsfiddle allows you in include the jQuery libraries natively and others, like elevatezoom, via URL.

Comment: Same question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234070/elevatezoom-disable-hidden-elements

Comment: ...and here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470394/elevate-zoom-not-working. Issue fairly clear, but solution remains outstanding